# Using "UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" Intent in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the following intent action, but i get an
`ActivityNotFoundException` in the first case (`startActivity`) and nothing in the second case (`sendBroadcast`).

```
"com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"
```

I try to use it with the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
startActivity(i);
```

Also with the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanted to remove my application shortcut from Home screen when certain condition is achieved. I managed doing it but with other way.

Comment: Answer your own question and give it the check mark ;)  Others might be trying to solve this too.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have the proper permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Then you need to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, your main activitiy);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
Intent removeIntent = new Intent();
removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent);
removeIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
removeIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
sendBroadcast(removeIntent);
```